# Leaflet map on click detect layer

Tags: layers, events

I added a click event to the map.

But when I click on a layer on the map, I want to disable this click event.

I have to write a condition in the map click event.

How can I find if there is a layer when clicking on the map?

```
this._map.on('click', (e)=>{
 if(/* what should I write? */){
  // code
 }else{
  // code
 }
})
```